# Rotate sns heatmap using pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap

I'm using pandas to import 256x256 numbers of data which I want to plot using (something similar to) sns.heatmap().

I read the data into a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df_Data = pd.read_csv(datapath,sep="\t",header=None)
```

As a trial run to see clearly what's happening my data looks like this (it doesn't have any labels as it's extracted directly from other software with just the raw numbers):

```
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 0 0 0 0 0 ..... 0
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 0 0 0 0 0 ..... 0
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 0 0 0 0 0 ..... 0
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 0 0 0 0 0 ..... 0
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 0 0 0 0 0 ..... 0
0 . ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... .
0 . ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 0
```

which produces this plot:
[image: Plot in original format]

I would like to rotate it by 270 degrees so that the highlighted part is in the bottom left corner, so that it looks like this (ideally with more sensible axis label formatting instead of what I did in ppt, but that's a detail):
[image: Rotate image]

I plot it with seaborn like this:

```
sns.heatmap(df_IntegratedData)
```

What's the most convenient way of doing this?

Comment: Would transposing/transforming the input data help you accomplish this? Or does it not get you to the orientation you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate the array in the dataframe using [`rot90`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html):

```
df_rot90 = pd.DataFrame(np.rot90(df_IntegratedData),
                        index=reversed(df_IntegratedData.columns),
                        columns=df_IntegratedData.index)
sns.heatmap(df_rot90)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = np.zeros((10,15))
data[0,0] = 1
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sns.heatmap(df)
```

[image]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.rot90(df), index=reversed(df.columns), columns=df.index)
sns.heatmap(df1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! In the end I did exactly the same thing but using numpy instead of pandas and it works exactly as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally this should be a transformation of the visualization instead of the underlying data, which is an inversion of your y-axis. However, since `matplotlib` does not implement a `swap_axes` type of API, you'll need to transpose your data.

To rotate a heatmap using pandas & matplotlib methods, you can draw a heatmap of the transposed dataframe, and then invert your y-axis:

### Transpose & Invert the y-axis

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.zeros((10,15))
data[0,0] = 1
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ax = sns.heatmap(df.T)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

### Side-by-side example

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.zeros((10,15))
data[0,0] = 1
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(16, 4))

sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('no changes')

sns.heatmap(df.T, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('transposed')

sns.heatmap(df.T, ax=ax3)
ax3.invert_yaxis()
ax3.set_title('transposed w/ inverted y-axis')
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants to _rotate_, not flip; see the axis ticks in the desired output and the text.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! some data manipulation is required after all, and I've updated my answer.